# UML Class diagram : Operation vs Association

Tags: uml, relation, class-diagram, operation

There are some cases that seem we can model something both as operation and as a relation. For example, imagine a scenario where we have a container that can load some components. One may model it as an association between container and component: `Container-loads->Components`, or as operation inside the container class: `+Load(c: Component)`. I wonder if both approaches are correct? if no, why?, if yes, so what is the main difference between an operation and a relation (here association)

Answer (score 1):

Operation and Relation are two completely different concepts. So you can't really compare them.

Most likely you want to compare attributes and associations. Attributes are typed and often you type them with another class. In that case it's best to replace the attribute with an association showing an owned property like so:

[image]

Note the dot which makes `class2` an (public; the `+`) owned property of `Class1`.

An operation will always have behavior. It may accept parameters and it may or may not return something. You can create an operation `class2` which returns an instance of `Class2` but that will be connected with some behavior. If not, creation of an operation would just be pointless and you'd use an attribute instead.